# How to create 8 processes

Tags: c, process, pid

I'm trying to get the following program create 8 processes instead of 6, but there's a catch. Of those 6 processes, 3 are parents. And of those 3 parents, 2 are child and parent processes (if I'm not mistaken) and 1 is exclusively child process. I want it to make 8 processes, increasing by 1 on the processes that are child and parent. That means I want the **3 parent processes** to end up having **3 child and parent processes**. Here's the code. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 2;
   pid_t p = fork();

   if (p > 0) x--;
   else if (p == 0)
   {
      pid_t t = fork();

      if (t > 0) x+=2;
      else if (t == 0) x+=3;
   }

   pid_t s = fork();
   printf("x = %d\n", x);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not see how that would add up to 8? Can you please describe the process hiearchy in more detail?

Comment: ASCII art is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Well, whenever you use fork(), it kinda "duplicates" the following code from where you used fork(). If you use a fork within a condition, it would create 2 processes. This program creates 6, if you use a fork() inside, lets say, if(p>0), wouldnt that have 8 total processes? Because that condition will only run when p is greater than 0 (that means when it's a parent process). I might be confused, if you don't understand what I'm saying or if I'm saying something wrong, could you please correct me and explain me? Thanks